# About pytorch occupy GPU memory

Tags: pytorch

Why does it occupy so much GPU memory when I use `.cuda()`? And how to reduce it? My poor 1660's GPU memory is so limited.

[image]

Comment: Did you make sure it was empty when you ran your python process?

Answer (score 0):

Execute--

```
torch.cuda.empty_cache()
```

It will reduce the GPU memory. If it does not reduce the memory, then restarting the kernel would solve the problem.

Comment: it does not work. and after I restart kernel, when i using .cuda(), it still occupy lot of GPU memory like i post above.